# Getting month as string in short form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, date

I want to get the month as a string but in short form, for example, I want to get Dec from 9/12/2015.

```
string month = date.ToString("MM"); //this give me the numerical value, not string

string month = date.Month;//this also give numerical value

strin month = date.ToString("MMMM"); //this give me the full name of month
```

How could i get 'Dec' from date?

Comment: `"MMM"` - refer [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

`string month = date.ToString("MMM");`